# Django double aggregation in one annotate

Tags: django

I try to find average in my QuerySet, I can not use `Avg` becouse column `mark` can place `None`.

So when I have value **2, 2, 3, None, None, 5** `Avg` return **3**

My idea is `Sum` value in column `mark` then divide by amount of `student`

This code `Sum` mark

```
student_mark = Mark.objects.filter(id_student__in=student_distinct_filtr_id).values('id_student').annotate(mark=Sum(F('mark')))
```

this `Count` student

```
student_amount = Mark.objects.filter(id_student__in=student_distinct_filtr_id).values('id_student').annotate(amount=Count('id_student'))
```

My question is how fild average?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're overcomplicating it. Why don't you calculate the average outside the queryset?

```
mark_qs = Mark.objects.filter(id_student__in=student_distinct_filtr_id)
marks = [mark.mark for mark in mark_qs if mark.mark is not None]
avg = sum(marks) / len(marks)
```

Anyway, your example is wrong. You say "*So when I have value 2, 2, 3, None, None, 5 `Avg` return 4*". That's not correct. It should be 3 (if you exclude the None values) or 2 (If you treat them as a 0).

Comment: This code return one avg for all mark, not specified avg for each student

Comment: You didn't stated that the average should be per student. Anyway, it should be easy: instead making a list with all the marks, make a dictionary with a student as the key, and the list of his marks as the values. Then calculate the average in the same way.

Comment: The point of calculating average in the query itself is lower number of database connections. Calculating outside query is simple but not efficient.